# 4 year old domain doesn't show up in google search results

Tags: google, search-results

when I google my own domain name, I don't even rank for it. Instead, my terms of service page gets indexed and shows up on the second page! My blog shows up here as well (it's hosted by another service) but my main home page and any of it's pages doesn't even appear on the search results.

I see the same thing on bing, and yahoo. Main page doesn't show up.

the domain name is not too generic but unique enough, it uses .la domain

Have I been banned from google? What the hell is going on?

The domain is 4 years old and I've done a redesign 4 months ago.

Comment: Was you maintaining SEO for that site since last 4 years??

Comment: The website has been online for the entire year.

Answer (score 0):

Have you check out Google webmaster tools? I suggest that you create a site map for your website and submit it using the Google webmaster tools if you haven't. Also, please check if there are any problems with your on page SEO and stuff.

Comment: Yes but there isn't any error messages. when I do `site: mysite.com` it doesn't show up in the results.